# Is it possible to override apache-servicemix cxf.xml file?

Tags: xml, cxf, apache-servicemix

I am using apache-servicemix and within it I have included karaf-cxf 3.1.13. Within the JAR file \META-INF\cxf\ is a cxf.xml file. I need to somehow override the parameters defined in this file for my own service mix distribution. Is it possible to somehow fully override this file within my own distribution or provide a way for the cxf to know to look up a different file?